# Query standard input of lightning-input

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, aura

I want to query standard HTML textarea which is wrapped by lightning-textarea. How can I get it?

```
<lightning-textarea name="secret_field" label="Secret" value={secretFieldValue}></lightning-textarea>
```

Comment: You can't, because of shadow DOM. What do you need it for?

Comment: @AlbaRivas I need to hide symbols in textarea but if I add css: -webkit-text-security: disc; it applied to label as well

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332903/how-to-mask-chars-in-lightning-textarea-input-similar-to-lightning-input-type-p

Answer (score 2):

For "secret" inputs, you want to use `<lightning-input type="password" />`. This provides the default "hidden" input characters as you'd expect.